# How to remove all evens in linked list java

Tags: java, nodes

How can I remove all the evens in a linked list in java? Other similar questions did not help me. I have a possible solution, but it seems too complicated. I'm not sure it even works.

```
public class Node {
public int value;
public Node next;
public Node (int val) {
    value = val;
}
public Node removeNode (Node root) {
    if (root == null || (root.next == null && isOdd(root.value))) {
        return null;
    }
    Node deep = root;
    while (deep.next != null) {
        deep = deep.next;
    }
    if (isOdd(deep.value)) {
        for (Node x = root; x != null; x = x.next) {
            if (isOdd(x.next.value)) {
                x.next = x.next.next;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (Node x = root; x.next != null; x = x.next) {
            if (isOdd(x.next.value)) {
                x.next = x.next.next;
            }
        }
    }
    if (isOdd(root.value)) {
        root = root.next;
    }
    return root;
}
public boolean isOdd (int val) {
    return (val % 2 == 1);
}
```

How can I improve this solution?

Comment: You shouldn't mix the logic of removing a node from a linked list with worrying about whether or not the value of a node is even. If you need to remove a node based on some other condition later, you'll to copy all the "remove node" code to another function, just to change what decides whether or not a node is deleted. Create a function that takes a predicate (a function that returns true/false), and use that to decide whether or not a node is deleted.

Comment: @BrandonChen I've edited my post to make it easier and cleaner. Let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: The `remove` method should be in your `LinkedList` class, not in the `Node` class itself!

After that it's quite easy to just remove the the even ones:

```
public class LinkedList {
    private Node root;

    public void removeEvens() {
        if (root == null) return;

        // removing all even nodes after the root
        Node prev = root;
        while (prev.next != null) {
            if (isEven(prev.next))
                prev.next = prev.next.next;   // next is even: delete it
            else
                prev = prev.next;             // next is not even: proceed
        }

        // delete root if it's even
        if (isEven(root))
            root = root.next;
    }

    private boolean isEven(Node node) {
        return node.value % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an element before root node. In that case you don't have to write code for check root node.

```
public class Node {
    public int value;
    public Node next;

    public Node(){}

    public Node (int val) {
        value = val;
    }

    public static Node removeEvens (Node root) {
        Node head = new Node();
        head.next = root;

        for (Node node = head; node.next!=null; node=node.next) 
           if (isEven(node.next))
                node.next = node.next.next;

        return head.next;
    }

    public static boolean isEven(Node node) {
        return node.value % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```